# How I can check if a string contais "x" but not "xy"

Tags: php, string, contains

How can I check if a string contains "x" but not "xy"?

So I have strings like this:

```
"5103564-XY",
"77-546-00X",
"292196232",
"5102200X",
"5102205",
"5102251-EP".
...
```

I only need the numbers which have the letter "x" at the end. Can Someone help me to realize that in PHP?

So if I try this:

```
$strings = array("5103564-AD", "77-546-00D", "292196232", "5102200D", "5102205", "5102251-EP");
print_r(preg_grep('/d$/i', $strings));
```

So the output is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5103564-AD
    [1] => 77-546-00D
    [3] => 5102200D
)
```

But this is not the wished result. I Only need the strings, which contains only the letter "D" and not the strings, which contains "AD" or somethingelse too. I hope it is now a little bit clearer, what I need/mine.

Comment: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php ](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Use `if (strpos($str, 'x') && strpos($str, 'xy') === false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to find only values in the list which end in just a `d` or `D` (with no preceding letter):

```
$strings = array("5103564-AD", "77-546-00D", "292196232", "5102200D", "5102205", "5102251-EP");
print_r(preg_grep('/[^a-z]d$/i', $strings));
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => 77-546-00D
    [3] => 5102200D
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Am4Vt)

Comment: Ok, thats right, but if I exchange the "x" to a "d", because the "x" in the example in reality was an "d" (the same in the strings, for an example "77-546-00X" is in reality "77-546-00D" ) and if I replace that in my Code, so the Answer is not right, can you help me? Here can you see what I min: https://3v4l.org/m1Fin

Comment: In what way is the answer not right? It is listing all the values that end in a `d`...

Comment: Yes, that is right, but I only need the strings, which only contains "D" not "DA", "XD", "YD" or somethingelse, only which has the letter "D" at the end, that is very important. ;-)

Comment: @Laberkopf I have modified my answer and demo. I think that should do what you want.